# Rename Power BI dataflow using Power BI REST API - 401 Unauthorised

Tags: python, azure, powerbi, adal

I would like to use Python to rename dataflows in our Power BI tenancy using the Power BI API endpoint [update dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/dataflows/updatedataflow), but I am receiving an authorisation error.

Following the [Microsoft guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/register-app?tabs=customers%2CAzure) I have:

- Create an Azure app
- Granted the `Dataflow.ReadWrite.All` permissions
- Added the service principal to a security group
- Updated the Power BI tenancy settings to allow the new security group to run Power BI APIs
- Granted access to the workspace to the security group and service principal

When I run the code below I receive `<Response [401]>`, however similar code I have written for other end points such as [get dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/dataflows/getdataflows) or [refresh dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/dataflows/refreshdataflow) work fine. If I remove all the Power BI API permissions from the Azure app it is still able to run the get and refresh calls. It is like the code is using the user permissions for the workspace and not picking up the app permissions.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

**Python**

```
import adal
import requests

TENANT_ID = "abc-123"
CLIENT_ID = "def-456"
CLIENT_SECRET = "ghi-789"
WORKSPACE_ID = "jkl-987"
DATAFLOW_ID = "mno-654"

authority_url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/"+TENANT_ID

context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority_url)

token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(
    resource="https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api",
    client_id=CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
)

access_token = token.get("accessToken")
token_type = token.get("tokenType")

tokenString = "{} {}".format(token_type, access_token)

header = {"Authorization": tokenString}

newName = "This is a new name"
body = {"name": newName}

refresh_url = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{}/dataflows/{}".format(WORKSPACE_ID, DATAFLOW_ID) #get all meta for specific dataflow

r = requests.patch(url=refresh_url, headers=header, json = body)

print(r)
```

Comment: It seems the permission `Dataflow.ReadWrite.All` is in Delegated type, but you use [client credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token) flow in your code to get access token. So could you please use [username/password](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) flow instead to get the access token in your code ?

Comment: Please try with this [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/adal/adal.authentication_context.authenticationcontext?view=azure-python#acquire-token-with-username-password-resource--username--password--client-id-) or this [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/adal/adal.authentication_context.authenticationcontext?view=azure-python#acquire-token-with-authorization-code-authorization-code--redirect-uri--resource--client-id--client-secret-none--code-verifier-none-).

Comment: Hi Simon, any update ?

Comment: Hi @HuryShen thanks for your help. I have now tried using the username/password method but get `AADSTS53003: Access has been blocked by Conditional Access policies.The access policy does not allow token issuance.` So it looks like the ability to issue tokens for user accounts has been blocked on our tenancy. I would try acquire_token_with_authorization_code but I don't know how to get the authorization code.

Comment: May I know if your problem was solved ? If the problem was solved, could you please mark the answer as "accepted", thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the help on this @HuryShen, I'm in the process of working through your solution...apologies for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

According to the description you provided in comments, it seems you have enabled MFA. So when you use [username/password](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) flow, it will be blocked.

[image]

So you can just use [auth code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) flow to get access token. You need to use the method [acquire_token_with_authorization_code(authorization_code, redirect_uri, resource, client_id, client_secret=None, code_verifier=None)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/adal/adal.authentication_context.authenticationcontext?view=azure-python#acquire-token-with-authorization-code-authorization-code--redirect-uri--resource--client-id--client-secret-none--code-verifier-none-). I think you know all of the parameters in method except `authorization_code`. You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code) to know how to get it.
[image]

Request the url with the parameters follow the url, it will redirect to the redirect uri which you specified in the request and follow a parameter named `code=...`. The value of `code` is `authorization_code`.

Here I provide my request sampel(use auth code flow) for your reference:

I request the url: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=xxxxx&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://hurytest&response_mode=query&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default&state=12345&nonce=67890`

[image]

It will ask me to login. After login, it will redirect to the uri `https://hurytest/` with `code` following.
[image]

The `code` is `authorization code`. You can use the code to do next step.

By the way, please pay attention to the `scope` and `resource` of the request. I use v2.0 endpoint in my sample, so I use `scope` instead of `resource`, but I noticed you use `resource` in your code(v1.0 endpoint use `resource`).